# Change state with api post call

Tags: css, reactjs, mongodb, api, react-hooks

hope you are well.
Im working on application for an online casino, I made a multistream app to show all the streams, I simply want to make that when a stream **isLive=False** (on Database) I want it to show an alert.
So far I have only succedded with **forceUpdate()** but this is breaking my application.

```
  const Tables = ({cat,filters,operator,}) => {
    const [tables, setTables] = useState([])
    const [filteredTables, setFilteredTables] = useState([])
    const [isLive, setIsLive] = useState([])
    const [reducerValue, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1,0)
        useEffect(()=>{
        const getTables = async ()=> {
            try{
                const res = await axios.get(
                    cat? 
                    `http://localhost:5000/api/tables?gameType=${cat}`
                    :
                    `http://localhost:5000/api/tables`
                    )
                    setTables(res.data)
                    // const newTables = setTables(res.data);
                    // setTables (oldTables => [...oldTables, newTables]);
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        };
        getTables()
        forceUpdate()
    }, [cat,isLive,reducerValue])
```

**CSS and HTML**

```
{table.isLive ?  
                            <TableNameLive> {table.name}  </TableNameLive> 
                            :
                            <TableNameDown> Stream Is Down for {table.name} </TableNameDown> 
                        }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution

```js
const getTables = async () => {
   try{
         const res = await axios.get(
         cat? 
            `http://localhost:5000/api/tables?gameType=${cat}`
              :
            `http://localhost:5000/api/tables`
         )
         return res.data
         // const newTables = setTables(res.data);
         // setTables (oldTables => [...oldTables, newTables]);
       }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
}

useEffect(()=>{
        setTables(getTables())
        forceUpdate()
    }, [cat,isLive,reducerValue])
```

This solution should help.

Thanks :)

Comment: im sorry but this did not work for me :(